# Creating a tar stream of arbitrary data and size

Tags: tar

I need to create an arbitrarily large tarfile for testing but don't want it to hit the disk.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use python to generate such a tarfile:

`mktar.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import sys
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout, mode="w|")

info = tarfile.TarInfo(name="fizzbuzz.data")
info.mode = 0644
info.size = 1048576 * 16
info.mtime = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s'))

rand = open('/dev/urandom', 'r')

tar.addfile(info,rand)
tar.close()
```

---

```
michael@challenger:~$ ./mktar.py | tar tvf -
-rw-r--r-- 0/0        16777216 2012-08-02 13:39 fizzbuzz.data
```

Comment: Note: This will drain your system's entropy on Linux. Not necessarily a problem, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Not when using urandom. I just tested it and my entropy_avail actually went from 129 to 184.

Comment: Using urandom pulls some entropy from the pool, though it is not dependent on the entropy pool like `random`; more likely than not it triggered a low watermark and the system generated more entropy before you checked. It's also possibly your system has a HRNG.

Comment: It'll pull a bit from the pool, but certainly not drain it. No HRNG here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tar with -O option `tar -O`, like this `tar -xOzf foo.tgz bigfile | process`

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-Standard-Output.html

PS: However, it could be, that you will not get the benefits you intend to gain as tar starts writing stdout only after it has read through the entire compressed file. You can demonstrate this behavior by starting a large file extraction and following the file size over time; it should be zero most of the processing time and start growing at very late stage. On the other hand I haven't researched this extensively, there might be some work around, or I might be just plain wrong with my first hand out-of-memory experience.